# Running into directory issues when running the container when using docker to launch jupyter notebooks. docker -v mount also not working properly

Tags: docker, github, containers

I am following the instructions from this repository https://github.com/CosmiQ/CosmiQ_SN7_Baseline

I. Download Data and Create Environment

```
Download SpaceNet 7 Data

The SpaceNet data is freely available on AWS, and all you need is an AWS account and the AWS CLI installed and configured. Once you’ve done that, simply run the command below to download the training dataset to your working directory (e.g. /local_data/sn7/aws_download/):

 cd /local_data/sn7/aws_download/
 aws s3 cp s3://spacenet-dataset/spacenet/SN7_buildings/tarballs/SN7_buildings_train.tar.gz .
 aws s3 cp s3://spacenet-dataset/spacenet/SN7_buildings/tarballs/SN7_buildings_test_public.tar.gz .

Extract data from the tarballs:

  cd /local_data/sn7/aws_download/
  tar -xvf SN7_buildings_train.tar.gz
  tar -xvf SN7_buildings_test_public.tar.gz

Download SpaceNet 7 baseline code to the desired location (e.g. /path_to_baseline/):

 cd /path_to_baseline/
 git clone https://github...
```

However I can't understand that once I run the image [(command 3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCZHw.png) and enter into interactive bash shell, how am I supposed to run the jupyter notebooks from inside the container.

STEP3:

Build and launch the docker container, which relies upon Solaris (a GPU-enabled machine and nvidia-docker are recommended):

commands to run in step 3

```
 nvidia-docker build -t sn7_baseline_image /path_to_baseline/docker 
 NV_GPU=0 nvidia-docker run -it -v /local_data:/local_data  -ti --ipc=host --name sn7_gpu0 sn7_baseline_image
 conda activate solaris
```

STEP4:Execute commands

This is a problem for me since when I run the commands in step3 I enter into bash shell having no access to the baseline

```
Either use the jupyter notebook:

 cd /path_to_baseline/
 jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port=9111 --no-browser --allow-root &

Locally in your browser, visit:

 http://localhost:9111

Or simply copy the relevant commands into a terminal within the docker container
```

The current directory is empty [using ls command to see if any file present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3zQW.png).
(solaris) root@c0011f0fc9bf:/tmp# ls

solaris  tmp2rhskj3a_kernels

(solaris) root@c0011f0fc9bf:/tmp# cd ..

(solaris) root@c0011f0fc9bf:/# ls

basel  bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  local_data  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var

(solaris) root@c0011f0fc9bf:/#

The command  NV_GPU=0 nvidia-docker run -it -v /local_data:/local_data in step3 doesnt mount anything to my folder in /var/lib/docker/volumes/

I am a beginner at dockers and running containers so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since externally linked information can change or disappear, in order to make your question useful for future readers, please edit the question to have all the necessary information to understand your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I cant embed photos directly into the post since I don't have 10 reputations.